# passing args to shell module in Ansible adhoc command

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to pass `args`, to the shell module when running it as an adhoc command?

I can pass the `free_form` parameter using `-a`, but I am trying to figure out how to specify additional arguments, such as `chdir` or `executable`.

For example, what is the adhoc equivalent to this task?

```
- name: Change working dir to somedir/ and run somescript.sh using bash
  shell: somescript.sh >> somelog.txt
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Append the parameters after the command. See the example below.

```
# ansible -m shell --args "pwd; touch test; ls -1 chdir=/scratch/tmp creates=/scratch/tmp/test" localhost
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
/scratch/tmp
test

# ansible -m shell --args "pwd; touch test; ls -1 chdir=/scratch/tmp creates=/scratch/tmp/test" localhost
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
skipped, since /scratch/tmp/test exists
```